# Reassigning values in a character array of pointers to other locations within that array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C how do I assign location [i-1] in a char array of pointers to location i in that same array?

For instance, say I have declared `char *word[m->words_in_msg+1];`

If I wanted to assign the location of i-1 to i how would I do that?  I currently have a for loop as such:

```
    for (int i = 2; i < m->words_in_msg; i++){
         &word[i - 1] = &word[i];
    }
```

However, this is giving me the compile error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment".  I think this is because it is reading the left hand side `&word[i - 1]` as a pointer location instead of a value but I'm not sure how I would tell it that the value stored in that location is what I want to reassign.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!  The C pointer mechanics are not strong with this one. : P

Comment: if you want to access the array element, why are you even fiddling around with a pointer to it? (you can't change the address of an object anyway.) Why not `word[i - 1] = word[i];`?

Comment: The error you are getting is saying that the thing on the left side of the equals sign is not a variable and this is correct. &word[i-1] refers to the address of word[i-1] and not to the value of it. Without getting too complicated one way to think about this is that your code tells the compiler to make a temporary variable and assign to this temp thing the address where word[i-1] is stored. This variable ceases to exist at the end of the instruction, so you cannot assign anything to it, that is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is not clear whether these pointers were dynamically allocated. If they were dynamically allocated and the array is the owner of the pointers then the code will look like

```
free( word[1] );
for (int i = 2; i < m->words_in_msg; i++)
{
     word[i - 1] = word[i];
}
```

If the pointers were not dynamically allocated or the array is not the owner of the pointers then you may write simply

```
for (int i = 2; i < m->words_in_msg; i++)
{
     word[i - 1] = word[i];
}
```

Take into account that you could use standard function `memmove` declared in header `<string.h>`

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem.  I was incorrectly accessing the elements in the pointer array and I was not freeing the memory that had already been allocated.  Once I did that it worked.  However, I researched the memmove function you mentioned and found that to be easier to use so went that route instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already declared an array of pointers, you just have to pass it adress, `word[some_index]` already hold it.

```
word[i - 1] = word[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put each element to the next position, you shouldn't iterate from first to last. Otherwise, you'll overwrite the element in the next position before moving it.

Comment: The assignment is to the left side of the assignment operator.  Ie, the element in position i is assigned to i - 1.  If you walk forward assigning the previous element to the element in the current position I don't believe that you do write over the current element until it has been stored in the i - 1 position.

Comment: Yeah, you are write. My mistake.